# Cant' Access port 8080 from browser even if its open at 0.0.0.0

Tags: virtualhost

`netstat -plnt` shows that my port `8080` is listening at `0.0.0.0` but I can't access it with external IP where as `localhost:8080` works just fine

[image]

If it shows this shouldn't I be able to access this using the servers IP using `http://167.99.144.42:8080/` or do I need to forward the port for some reason.

I am using Apache2 on Ubuntu and Nodejs.

Comment: didn't you allow port 8080 in firewall or security policy?

Answer (score 0):

167.99.144.42 on port 8080 and 22 is working fine from the public Internet

There is probably a problem with access from your browser such as a local proxy